# google drive api file download. WebcontentLink is NULL

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am trying to download a file via google api. I came across that I need to retrive a webContentLink but unfortunetly this property is st

This is my code a part of my code:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

// Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
$optParams = array(
  'pageSize' => 1,
  'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

$zdjecie = '/home/bachus03/domains/bachus03.vot.pl/public_html/fb/public/test.jpg';

if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
  print "No files found.\n";
} else {
  print "Files:\n";
  foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $file->getName(), $file->getId());
    $file_full = $service->files->get($file->getId());
    /*printFile($service, $file_full);
    file_put_contents($zdjecie, $file_content);
    print "zapisano zdjecie"; */
    var_dump($file_full);
  }
```

and this is what I get in output:

```
[bachus03@s14:: ~ ]:$ /usr/local/php/p56/bin/php /home/bachus03/domains/bachus03.vot.pl/public_html/fb/public/quickstart.php

Files:
20161209_170813.JPG (1Nt9twwwwj-D2qKpmIga_T0pRCs2JxvyfvA)
object(Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile)#53 (56) {
  ["collection_key":protected]=>
  string(6) "spaces"
  ["appProperties"]=>
  NULL
  ["capabilitiesType":protected]=>
  string(42) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileCapabilities"
  ["capabilitiesDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["contentHintsType":protected]=>
  string(42) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileContentHints"
  ["contentHintsDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["createdTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["description"]=>
  NULL
  ["explicitlyTrashed"]=>
  NULL
  ["fileExtension"]=>
  NULL
  ["folderColorRgb"]=>
  NULL
  ["fullFileExtension"]=>
  NULL
  ["headRevisionId"]=>
  NULL
  ["iconLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["id"]=>
  string(35) "1Nt9twwwwj-D2qKpmIga_T0pRCs2JxvyfvA"
  ["imageMediaMetadataType":protected]=>
  string(48) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileImageMediaMetadata"
  ["imageMediaMetadataDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["isAppAuthorized"]=>
  NULL
  ["kind"]=>
  string(10) "drive#file"
  ["lastModifyingUserType":protected]=>
  string(25) "Google_Service_Drive_User"
  ["lastModifyingUserDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["md5Checksum"]=>
  NULL
  ["mimeType"]=>
  string(10) "image/jpeg"
  ["modifiedByMeTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["modifiedTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["name"]=>
  string(19) "20161209_170813.JPG"
  ["originalFilename"]=>
  NULL
  ["ownedByMe"]=>
  NULL
  ["ownersType":protected]=>
  string(25) "Google_Service_Drive_User"
  ["ownersDataType":protected]=>
  string(5) "array"
  ["parents"]=>
  NULL
  ["permissionsType":protected]=>
  string(31) "Google_Service_Drive_Permission"
  ["permissionsDataType":protected]=>
  string(5) "array"
  ["properties"]=>
  NULL
  ["quotaBytesUsed"]=>
  NULL
  ["shared"]=>
  NULL
  ["sharedWithMeTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["sharingUserType":protected]=>
  string(25) "Google_Service_Drive_User"
  ["sharingUserDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["size"]=>
  NULL
  ["spaces"]=>
  NULL
  ["starred"]=>
  NULL
  ["thumbnailLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["trashed"]=>
  NULL
  ["version"]=>
  NULL
  ["videoMediaMetadataType":protected]=>
  string(48) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileVideoMediaMetadata"
  ["videoMediaMetadataDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["viewedByMe"]=>
  NULL
  ["viewedByMeTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["viewersCanCopyContent"]=>
  NULL
  ["webContentLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["webViewLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["writersCanShare"]=>
  NULL
  ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["modelData":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["processed":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

What a i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The other main part is you will have to do a `files.get` request from the id returned in the `files.insert` call - you will not be able to do it in a single API call on just the insert.

webContentLink can be accessed once the Files resource were retrieve (ie, using get). Based on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#viewing_files_in_a_browser). Insert should be able to have webContentLink as well since it also uses Files resources for its response

Comment: Thanks, for anver but I already solved my problem, in v3 I need to specify what filed i need, there is no more all filed ny default. I am not using drive as a free public hosting serive I use id to ingerate picures form a fiew devices, and then retouch them using makeup.pho.to api (wchih seems not worinkg at the moment) and then publish on facebook and wordpress site :)